# UEFI but not booting directly

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi, gpt, efi

I was playing around with my partitions finally now it doesn't boot directly. For it to boot I need to go to HP boot menu and then choose EFI file to boot to load the OS. Something like EFI partition is there but not active boot. However when I checked the flags the drive has boot flag set. Not sure what's wrong. If I don't press F9 while booting and choose EFI file it simply halts saying no OS found.[image: GDisk Structure]

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be able to fix it using `bcdedit` in Windows, as described here:

[Windows 8 changes boot order](https://superuser.com/questions/525953/windows-8-changes-boot-order)

Unfortunately, many HPs have a known firmware bug that prevents them from working correctly. If you've got this problem, you'll have to rename your boot loader files so that the firmware *thinks* it's booting Windows when in fact it's launching GRUB (or rEFInd, or gummiboot, or whatever else you prefer to use as a boot manager). If you're using Ubuntu or a related distribution, the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool can do this job semi-automatically, using an option on the Advanced menu to "back up and rename boot loader files" (or words to that effect; I don't recall the precise wording). Boot Repair might even work on distributions unrelated to Ubuntu, but the odds are better the closer it is to Ubuntu. See [this section](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html#alternative-naming) of a page of mine if you prefer to do it manually.